# Setting up Icon for the exe produced by py2exe for console

Tags: python, console, icons, py2exe, setup.py

This is my code, i couldn't able to set up an icon for exe using py2exe.  This code  successfully generates the exe file and works properly but i couldnt set the icon. Python version :2.5 py2exe version : 0.6.9 , Window :8.1, Icon File Siz 32*32

Thanks In Advance

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
console = [
    {
        "script": "image-fetcher.py",
        "icon_resources": [(0,"icon.ico")],
    }
],
zipfile = None,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Resource Hacker™](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/)

After installing Ressource Hacker, go to File -> Open (Your .exe) 
Then you'll get PYTHONSCRIPT, Icon... on your right : Right click on Icon -> Replace Icon -> then open your .ico file  -> Replace
When done Save modification,

Answer (score 0):

```
setup_dict = dict(console=[{'script':'script.py','icon_resources':[(0,'myicon.ico')]}])
setup(**setup_dict)
```

This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console = [
        {
            "script": 'script.py',     
            "icon_resources": [(0, "myicon.ico")]
        }
    ],
)
```

Found this on site [over here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/CustomIcons); good timing--was nearly going to post this question behind you.